# How do I compute the key of a MAC with given Hashfunction and some parameters?

Tags: security, key, ascii

I'm attempting to compute the key of a Message Authentication Code (MAC).
The following is given:

```
 c_i = h(c_i-1, x_i) = c_i-1 xor x_i for i from 1 to z.
Furthermore MAC_k(m) = c_z + key mod 2^8
And now I have These values: m = KINOSAAL (ASCII 8 Bit)
MAC_k(m) = 01101011 and c_0 = 11111111
```

Now I attempted this Approach, but I am sure it must be wrong :( But Maybe some Approach is correct, so I would be glad if you guys could help me out.

```
K = 4B
I = 49
N = 4E
O = 4F
S = 53
A = 41
A = 41
L = 4C
? = 3F

c0 = 11111111 = FF

MAC_k(m) = 01101011 = 6B

c1 = c0 xor x1 = FF xor 4B = B4
c2 = c1 xor x2 = B4 xor 49 = FD
c3 = c2 xor x3 = FD xor 4E = B3
c4 = c3 xor x4 = B3 xor 4F = FC
c5 = c4 xor x5 = FC xor 53 = AF
c6 = c5 xor x6 = AF xor 41 = EE
c7 = c6 xor x7 = EE xor 41 = AF
c8 = c7 xor x8 = AF xor 4C = E3
c9 = c8 xor x9 = E3 xor 3F = DC  => c_z = DC (hex)

=> k = m xor cz = 6B xor DC = B7 (HEX)
```

That's my Approach. Thanks in Advance and Kind regards